# Relaxing rules for execution order

Tags: c++, c, optimization

The C and C++ standards specify that the order of execution must strictly follow the source instructions order. A compiler is free to evaluate the sub-expressions in an instruction in any order, but cannot reorder instructions separated with a semi-colon or a colon.

For example, in the instruction:

```
A = A + B * C + D * E;
```

The compiler might choose to perform D*E before B*C, or add A at the end.

If the same computation is now split in various instructions:

```
int t1 = B * C;
t1 += D * E;
A += t1;
```

In this case, the compiler cannot evaluate D * E after B * C.

Generally, this sort of code is slightly slower because the compiler cannot optimize the order the CPU instructions for a specific hardware.

What I wish to do is the opposite way. If for example the body of an unrolled loop reads:

```
A[0] = B[0] * C[0];
A[1] = B[1] * C[1];
A[2] = B[2] * C[2];
A[3] = B[3] * C[3];
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that these four instructions can be evaluated in any order since they operate on separate data ? Even a non-portable trick is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that's what the spec says about reordering? I am having trouble finding this in the spec. I believe all modern compilers will freely reorder as you're asking for in this case, and I had thought that to be specification-compliant.

Comment: I think the compiler could reorder these and do them in parallel, using the *as-if* rule. If your compiler won't, then use SIMD instructions to get the operations performed in parallel.

Comment: Have you tried [`restrict`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict)?

Comment: @Mysticial I don't see how `restrict` would do anything here.

Comment: @Pubby Without `restrict` or some other information, the compiler can't prove that `A,B,C` don't overlap and thus will not be allowed to reorder the statements.

Comment: @zmccord As-written the compiler cannot safely reorder because you might have A == B + 1 for example.

Comment: @Mysticial Oh, my mistake. I thought it was just `A`'s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The C and C++ standards specify that the order of execution must strictly follow the source instructions order.

Not quite. They say that the *observable behaviour* of the program - that is, I/O operations and accesses to volatile objects - must occur *as if* that were the case. The compiler is still free to reorder evaluations as it likes, provided it does not change the program's behaviour. As long as your assignment and multiplication operations don't have observable side effects, your code can be reordered.

However, things are more problematic when you're using pointers or references. In general, the compiler can't tell that `A`, `B` and `C` point to different regions of memory, so it must assume that an assignment to `A` might change one of the `B` or `C` values used later. Therefore it can't reorder the evaluations. In C, you could use `restrict` to tell the compiler that they don't overlap, but no such feature exists in standard C++. (That's not a problem if they are arrays, in which case the compiler knows that they don't overlap.)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler only have to apply the "as-if" rule. Observable behavior has to stay as expected, but if the compiler can conclude that these operations do not affect each other it is free to do them in any order.

Answer (score 1):

You may use comma operator.
Or you may use OpenMP if the target platform is multicore architecture.

```
A[0] = B[0] * C[0],
A[1] = B[1] * C[1],
A[2] = B[2] * C[2],
A[3] = B[3] * C[3];
```

P. S. Actually it's not right answer to use comma.
So probably explicit parallelism is an answer. Or the function call, as in the neighbor answer.

Answer (score 1):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is undefined in C and C++. So you could do something like this:

```
template<typename T> void f(T a, T b)
{
}

f( A[0] = B[0] * C[0], A[1] = B[1] * C[1] );
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
void eval_any_order(...) {}

eval_any_order(
  A[0] = B[0] * C[0],
  A[1] = B[1] * C[1],
  A[2] = B[2] * C[2],
  A[3] = B[3] * C[3]
);
```

The compiler will likely reorder them already though - it can so long as the outcome is the same.